# Map of Accounts indexed by Opportunity Id

Tags: account, map

I'm writting a code at Opportunity's before insert trigger. There, I want to create a Map of Account's related to all Trigger.new oportunities indexed by theirs opportunity ID. I expect that each Map entry to be something like this: Key=OpportunityID; Value=Account Object.
Could someone help me with the aprpriate statement to achieve it? I'm suppose this could be acomplished using a soql statement in the Map initialization.

Best regards,

Saulo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one of the answers, and you can always make it better

```
// It's the map you want
Map<Id,Account> mapO_A = new Map<Id,Account>();

// First of all, get the opportunities from database
Map<Id,Opportunity> mapOO = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Opportunity]);

// Now let's get the accountId
Set<Id> accountId = new Set<Id>();
for(Opportunity op : mapOO.values()){
    accountId.add(op.AccountId);
}

// Get the account you want
Map<Id,Account> mapAA = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountId]);

// Put them together
for(Id opId : mapOO.keySet()){
    Id acctId = mapOO.get(opId).AccountId;
    mapO_A.put(opId,mapAA.get(acctId));
}

// Done
System.debug(mapO_A);
```

Answer (score 5):

The map constructor can only sort by the object ID of the `list<object>` you pass to it. (This is what you actually do when you pass on a soql query)

```
Map<Id,Account> map = new Map<Id,Account>([select id, name from account]);
```

**The map you're looking for will need to be done in Apex**

1) compose a `map< account Id, opportunity Id>` by iterating your trigger.new collection

2) query the accounts based on the keyset

3) iterate your result and fill a `map<opportunity Id, account ID>` by looking up the opportunity Id from the first map.

Answer (score -1):

In Apex, you can create any sort of `map`.  The first thing to consider is the structure of a `map` / how it works.  A `map` contains two elements:  the `keyset` and the `values` list.
The `keyset`, as the name implies, is a `set` -- therefore it stores **no** duplicate values.  The map's `values` is a `list` -- so it *can* have duplicate values.

To create a map, first you need to construct it, so let's create a fresh new map to work with:

```
map<string,integer> myFirstMap = new map<string,integer>();
```

Now, we need to put elements into the map.  By the way we defined our map, it takes `strings` as its input and gives `integers` as its output.  So, let's give our map some elements.  Use the `put` method to insert elements into the map.

```
myFirstMap.put('a',1);
myFirstMap.put('b',42);
myFirstMap.put('ab',1);
myFirstMap.put('25',6);
```

Now to get the value, use the `get` method of the map.

```
integer a_value = myFirstMap.get('a');   
system.assertEquals(a_value,1);

system.assertEquals(myFirstMap.get('a'),myFirstMap.get('ab'));
```

To access the map's `keyset` and `values`, use the `keyset()` and `values()` methods, respectively.

```
set<string> theKeyset = myFirstMap.keyset();
list<integer> theValues = myFirstMap.values();
```

And that's pretty much it for the map methods.  The big thing to consider is that the keyset is a set.  What if you do the following?

```
myFirstMap.put('hey there',88);
myFirstMap.put('hey there',420);

system.assertEquals(myFirstMap.get('hey there', xxxx );  //  what's xxxx?
// answer:  xxxx = 420
```

The map will store only the last value given for a specific key.  Another consideration is "What happens if you try to get a key that has never been set?"

```
system.assertEquals(myFirstMap.get('this key has never been set X_X'),null);
```

---

Now to specifically address your question:  Suppose we want to get a `list<Account>` via SOQL query and then create a map with the Account's `OpportunityID` as its key.

```
list<Account>  accountList = [SELECT id,OpportunityID
                              FROM Account
                              WHERE OpportunityID!=null];

map<id,Account> oppIdAcctMap = new map<id,Account>();

for(Account a:accountList)
    oppIdAcctMap.put(a.OpportunityID,a);
```

Badda-bing!