# How to parse and concatenate map value?

Tags: apex, map

I am working on a trigger that will overwrite the opportunity name with the account name plus some generic text (e.g. 'Acme, Inc. [New Opportunity]'). This functionality can be handled by a workflow with a field update, but the trigger(s) will grow in complexity with additional logic for opportunity products.

I've borrowed and have applied examples from the posts [Map of Accounts indexed by Opportunity Id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25412/map-of-accounts-indexed-by-opportunity-id) and [How to Map Opportunity Owner to Account Owner](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29466/how-to-map-opportunity-owner-to-account-owner?rq=1). The challenge I am facing is that the output is not what I expected. Instead of 'Acme, Inc. [New Opportunity]' I get the following from debug:

> (Account:{Name=Acme, Inc., Id=001F00000174p9pIAA} [New Opportunity],
>   Account:{Name=Zenith, LLC., Id=001F00000174p9oIAA} [New Opportunity])

Here is the code that I've been working (will be converted to trigger):

```
>     Set<Id> opptyIdSet = new Set<Id>(); 

    opptyIdSet.add('006F000000SdrzX');
    opptyIdSet.add('006F000000TH8vS');

    // Map to pair Oppty Id to Account
    Map<Id,Account> mapOpptyAcct = new Map<Id,Account>();

    // Map to gather opptys in scope
    Map<Id,Opportunity> mapOpptys = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN: opptyIdSet]);

    // Collect set of Account Ids
    Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity op : mapOpptys.values()){
        accountIdSet.add(op.AccountId);
    }

    // Map the Account Ids to Account Names
    Map<Id,Account> mapAccounts = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIdSet]);

    // Put them together
    for(Id opId : mapOpptys.keySet()){
        Id acctId = mapOpptys.get(opId).AccountId;
        mapOpptyAcct.put(opId,mapAccounts.get(acctId));
    }

    // variable to hold concatenated Oppty Name
    String AccountName;
    String newInquiry = ' [New Opportunity]';
    String newOpptyName;

    // Map to hold Id and final Oppty Name 
    Map<Id, String> mapFinal = new Map<id, String>();

    // Iterate over Oppty Accoutn map and put in new Oppty Name
    for(Id opId : mapOpptyAcct.keySet()) {
        AccountName = String.valueOf(mapOpptyAcct.get(opId));
        newOpptyName = AccountName + ' [New Opportunity]';
        mapFinal.put(opId,newOpptyName);
    }

    // Test Concatenation
    System.debug('AccountName: ' + mapFinal.values());
```

How does one get to a clean output of the account name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
mapOpptyAcct.put(opId,mapAccounts.get(acctId));
```

You're putting the whole account record into that map, indexed by opportunity ID.

Then in this line:

```
AccountName = String.valueOf(mapOpptyAcct.get(opId));
```

You're getting that account back, and converting the whole thing to a `String` variable which is why you're getting all of the rest. Instead you want to just reference the name field:

```
AccountName = mapOpptyAcct.get(opId).Name;
```